OSM Overpass API: extract polygons of countries instead of lines
I am extracting ISO-3 codes of countries intersecting with the specific bounding boxes through the following Overpass query:
[out:json]
[maxsize:1073741824]
[timeout:9000]
[bbox:{{bbox}}];
nwr["boundary"="administrative"]["admin_level"="2"]["ISO3166-1:alpha3"~"^.+$"]; 
(._;>;);
out;

After a few tests, I've realised that it fetches features only if they are intersecting with the bounding box. If bounding box is located completely within the country, it gives me nothing.
For example, for the bounding box of Catalonia (intersects with three countries) it fetches features with from every country:
[out:json]
[maxsize:1073741824]
[timeout:9000]
[bbox:40.24452664923259,-0.17175642211838113,43.146655333714754,3.6946497219995114];
nwr["boundary"="administrative"]["admin_level"="2"]["ISO3166-1:alpha3"~"^.+$"]; 
(._;>;);
out;

And for the part of the UK with the following bounding box no features found:
[out:json]
[maxsize:1073741824]
[timeout:9000]
[bbox:52.98893670759685,-2.7876213063263044,54.755166952963556,-1.1889035388429525];
nwr["boundary"="administrative"]["admin_level"="2"]["ISO3166-1:alpha3"~"^.+$"]; 
(._;>;);
out;


That's how Overpass API works. If the elements you are searching for aren't located inside the given bounding box, they are not returned. Country polygons are mapped as individual ways along the border. If the border is not part of the bbox, these ways won't be part of the result. Fix your bounding box :)

I've suspected that, but there is another workaround in my mind: retrieve a collection of features with a larger 'admin_level'- they should be in abundance, cover smaller areas and have a relation to countries which they belong to.

@scai There should be some another workaround since the simple OSM browser with a custom bbox of any size and user-defined query for features in any point shows that it is located within some country (for example, https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/62149).

I'm not quite sure which query tool you are referring to but I guess it involves a geocoder such as Nominatim.
